# CSS Transitions as a result of jQuery DOM Manipulations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I ensure CSS transitions will occur as a result of moving elements in the DOM with jQuery?

The following CSS transition is ignored when relying on a last-child state selector. The style updates as expected, but there is no transition time to that style.

```
<ul>
<li>A</li>
<li>B</li>
<li>C</li>
</ul>

li {
  background-color: red;
}

li:last-child {
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: 3s ease;
}

// move list item to last place when clicked
$('li').click(function() {
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  $(this).detach().appendTo( parent );
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mychine/L3193Lgw/)

The only way I can seem to ensure a transition will occur is to add a class after a small setTimeout call, and not use a state selector.

```
li.activate {
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: 3s ease;
}

$('li').click(function() {
  var item = $(this);
  var parent = item.parent();
  item.detach().appendTo( parent );      
  setTimeout( function() {  
    parent.children().removeClass('activate');
    item.addClass('activate');
  }, 5 );
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mychine/6epuk6y4/)

Comment: You did not provide parameter for transition. What should have transition ? Another thing is you need to set transition for li element not the :last-child.

Comment: it's totally complicated. A moving item should *leave behind* some wrapper that 1. animates to the incoming element height and 2. than becomes the wrapper of that element.... and you need to do that for all moving elements :D

Comment: Another solution is: before moving all elements you calculate their states and make them absolute (like moving shapes on a canvas...) than after the transition is done you rebuild/reset DOM positions etc etc etc.... So all in all is all about `.animate()` or `transition` an absolute element before faking and rebuilding it's new position, meantime faking temporary wrappers animations and destroying them etc....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Twitchy. Remember to accept answers that solve your issue so that others can learn quicker from your questions. _You can always change your mind later!_

Comment: El Danielo, I agree I could flush it out more, defaulting to all in concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are just moving elements in the DOM tree, there's no *visual* state to transition *from*.
However you can use CSS animations which are triggered *also* by creating a new element.

There is no need to `.detach()` first.

```js
// move list item to last place when clicked
$('li').click(function() {
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  $(this).appendTo( parent );
});
```

```css
li {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
}

li:last-child {
  animation: pulse 1s 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    height: 50px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 90px;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively you can:

1. Move the element (`.appendTo`)
2. In the next loop (`setTimeout`, `requestAnimationFrame`, etc.) add a classname like 'last', which should in turn trigger the transition, because the element's CSS properties have changed *from* it's class-less state. *(which you kind of figured out already…)*

Comment: "There's no visual state to transition from"... thank you for that.